# change folders to packages in pydev eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

When I imported a django project, the app in the site imported as folders.  In my other projects, the apps are packages.

here is what it looks like:
[image]
How can I change the folders to packages?

Comment: Have you checked that the modules contains an `__init__.py` file?

Comment: yes it does have them

Comment: Ok, then make sure that you use the "PyDev" perspective in Eclipse.

Comment: You can also try to refresh the project and also make sure that you use a recent version of PyDev.

Comment: it works for all other prjects, just not this certain one.  It has a deep directory structure, I'm wondering if that is reason.

Comment: That might be it although it feels a bit strange though. Did you verify that you are using the PyDev perspective (Window -> Open Perspective -> PyDev) ?

Comment: yes i am. I also have other projects that are packages.  That is why I'm scratching my head.

Comment: Perhaps you should file a bug report on pydev?

Answer (score 3):

The difference between a folder and a package is that later is in PYTHONPATH. The easiest way: right click on the folder, scroll on the menu to PyDev and on the next menu choose "Set as a Source Folder..." You might need to refresh to see changes

[image]